# Next and previous buttons javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get alert when the user clicked next or previous button and its already at the first or last element of the array

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("f").value = person[arr].fname;
    document.getElementById("l").value = person[arr].lname;
    document.getElementById("a").value = person[arr].age;
    document.getElementById("s").value = person[arr].salary;
}

document.getElementById("prevbtn").addEventListener("click", myFunctionPrev);
document.getElementById("nxtbtn").addEventListener("click", myFunctionNext);


function myFunctionPrev() {
    if (arr > 0) {
        arr -= 1;
    }

    myFunction();
}



function myFunctionNext() {
    if (arr < 3) {
        arr += 1;
    }

    myFunction();
}
```

Comment: first would be `arr == 0` last would be `arr == person.length - 1` or as you have hardcoded the value `arr == 3`

Answer (score 0):

by "get alert" I don't know exactly your expectation but a nice way to alert the user that can't cross the limits it is disabling the button.

Here an example.

```js
var person = [{
        fname: "1",
        lname: "1",
        age: "1",
        salary: "1"
    }, {
        fname: "2",
        lname: "2",
        age: "2",
        salary: "2"
    },
    {
        fname: "3",
        lname: "3",
        age: "3",
        salary: "3"
    }];

var index = 0;
document.getElementById("prevbtn").addEventListener("click", myFunctionPrev);
document.getElementById("nxtbtn").addEventListener("click", myFunctionNext);
myFunction();

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("f").innerHTML = person[index].fname;
    document.getElementById("l").innerHTML = person[index].lname;
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = person[index].age;
    document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = person[index].salary;
    checkButtonStatus();
}

function checkButtonStatus() {
    document.getElementById("prevbtn").disabled = index <= 0;
    document.getElementById("nxtbtn").disabled = index >= person.length - 1;
}

function myFunctionPrev() {
    if (index > 0) {
        index -= 1;
    }

    myFunction();
}


function myFunctionNext() {
    if (index < person.length) {
        index += 1;
    }

    myFunction();
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div>
        <div id="f"></div>
        <div id="l"></div>
        <div id="a"></div>
        <div id="s"></div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="prevbtn">Prev</button>
        <button id="nxtbtn">Next</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

If you wish you can replace the enable/disable function with the alert that you need.